# UE5 when i receive data from the server and try to store data in a variable then game crashed and warning null error

Tags: unreal-engine5

I try make chatting with my echo server

I checked the log that the server connection and data transmission and reception are normal

Then I tried to save the data from the server in a variable and make it like a chat

but game was crash and warning null thorw error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiUVy.gif)

I checked the log that the server connection and data transmission and reception are normal

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1tBj.jpg)

Then I tried to save the data from the server in a variable and make it like a chat

but game was crash and warning null thorw error

i think i check null using if is not null but game crash and warning null throw
i cant understand why and how to fix it?

promblem is this function

void AParagonWorldPlayerController::RecvChat(const FString* chatdata)
{

```
if (chatdata !=nullptr) 
{   
    FString aa = *chatdata;
    if (*chatdata !="")
    {
        //bIsChatNeedUpdate = true;
        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Received data from server: %s"), *aa);
        GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 5.f, FColor::Red, FString::Printf(TEXT("Chat Data:%s"), *aa));
        message =*chatdata; // this point is problem variable type is FString
                                        // i think i check null using if (*chatdata !="")
                                        // but game crash and warning null throw 
                                        // i cant understand why and how to fix it?
    }
}
```

}

this is clientsocket.cpp

```
// Fill out your copyright notice in the Description page of Project Settings.


#include "ClientSocket.h"
#include <sstream>
#include "Runtime/Core/Public/GenericPlatform/GenericPlatformAffinity.h"
#include "Runtime/Core/Public/HAL/RunnableThread.h"
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include "Sockets.h"
#include "SocketSubsystem.h"
#include "ParagonWorldPlayerController.h"

#define PACKET_SIZE 1024

#include <iostream>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <thread>



#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

#pragma warning(disable : 4996)

#pragma region Main Thread Code



ClientSocket::ClientSocket()
{
    // 스레드 생성
    // this는 생성할 스레드 즉 clientsocket.cpp 스레드의 TEXT는 스레드의 이름 
    Thread = FRunnableThread::Create(this, TEXT("Network Thread"));
}

ClientSocket::~ClientSocket()
{
    // 스레드 종료
    Thread->WaitForCompletion();
    Thread->Kill();
    delete Thread;

    closesocket(Socket);
    WSACleanup();
}

#pragma endregion

bool ClientSocket::Init()
{
    UE_LOG(LogNet, Warning, TEXT("Thread has been initialized"));

    WSADATA wsa;
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa)) {

        GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 5.f, FColor::Red, FString::Printf(TEXT("wsa error")));
        WSACleanup();
        return false;
    }

    Socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (Socket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 5.f, FColor::Red, FString::Printf(TEXT("socket error")));
        closesocket(Socket);
        WSACleanup();
        return false;
    }
    
    return true;
}

FString * ClientSocket::RecvChat(FString & Recv) 
{
    sChat = Recv;
    return &sChat;
}

uint32 ClientSocket::Run()
{

    FPlatformProcess::Sleep(0.1);

    char buf[PACKET_SIZE];
    
    while (true)
    {
        // Recv 작업을 여기서 진행 하면된다.
        ZeroMemory(buf, PACKET_SIZE);
        //recv(Socket, buf, PACKET_SIZE, 0);

        int32 BytesReceived = recv(Socket, buf, PACKET_SIZE, 0);

        //buf[BytesReceived] = '\0';
        FString ReceivedData = FString(ANSI_TO_TCHAR(buf));

        const FString* ptr = &ReceivedData;

        const FString conData = FString(ANSI_TO_TCHAR(buf));

        //UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Received data from server: %s"), *ReceivedData);

        if (BytesReceived > 0) 
        {
            ParagonWorldPlayerController->RecvChat(RecvChat(ReceivedData));
        }

        if (WSAGetLastError()) break;

        //GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 5.f, FColor::Red, FString::Printf(TEXT(" % buf : %s "), buf));

    }

    return 0;
}

void ClientSocket::Exit()
{
    if (Socket)
    {
        // Socket 연결을 끊고 Winsock 사용을 종료
        // Disconnect Socket and terminate Winsock use
        closesocket(Socket);
        WSACleanup();
    }
}

bool ClientSocket::ConnectServer() 
{
    SOCKADDR_IN addr = {};
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(8000);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

    int nRet = connect(Socket, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, sizeof(addr));
    if (nRet == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

void ClientSocket::SendData(const FString& Data)
{

    if (Socket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Error, TEXT("Socket connect error."));
        return;
    }

    // FString을 UTF-8로 인코딩된 char 배열로 변환합니다.
    // Convert the FString to a char array encoded with UTF-8.
    const char* DataUtf8 = TCHAR_TO_UTF8(*Data);

    // 서버로 데이터 전송
    // Transferring data to server
    int DataLength = strlen(DataUtf8);
    int BytesSent = send(Socket, DataUtf8, DataLength, 0);

    if (BytesSent == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        // Failed to send data to server
        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Error, TEXT("서버로 데이터를 보내는데 실패하였습니다."));
        closesocket(Socket);
        WSACleanup();
        return;
    }
}
```

this is ParagonWorldPlayerController.cpp

```
// Fill out your copyright notice in the Description page of Project Settings.


#include "ParagonWorldPlayerController.h"
#include "Kismet/GameplayStatics.h"
#include "Blueprint/UserWidget.h"
#include <string>
#include "Kismet/GameplayStatics.h"
#include "ChatWindowWidget.h"
#include "TimerManager.h"
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

AParagonWorldPlayerController::AParagonWorldPlayerController()
{
    bIsChatNeedUpdate = false;
}

AParagonWorldPlayerController::~AParagonWorldPlayerController()
{

}

void AParagonWorldPlayerController::Tick(float DeltaTime)
{
    Super::Tick(DeltaTime);

    // 채팅 동기화
    //if (bIsChatNeedUpdate)
    //  UpdateChat();

    //SendPlayerInfo();
}

void AParagonWorldPlayerController::GetLifetimeReplicatedProps(TArray<FLifetimeProperty>& OutLifetimeProps) const
{
    Super::GetLifetimeReplicatedProps(OutLifetimeProps);
}

void AParagonWorldPlayerController::BeginPlay()
{
    Super::BeginPlay();


    Socket = ClientSocket::GetSingleton();
    Socket->Init();
    Socket->ConnectServer();

}

void AParagonWorldPlayerController::SendChat(const FString& Data)
{
    if (Data != "")
    {
        Socket->SendData(Data);
        //UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Send data to server: %s"), *Data);
    }
}


void AParagonWorldPlayerController::RecvChat(const FString* chatdata)
{

    if (chatdata !=nullptr) 
    {   
        FString aa = *chatdata;
        if (*chatdata !="")
        {
            //bIsChatNeedUpdate = true;
            UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Received data from server: %s"), *aa);
            GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 5.f, FColor::Red, FString::Printf(TEXT("Chat Data:%s"), *aa));
            message =*chatdata; // this point is problem variable type is FString
                                            // i think i check null using if (*chatdata !="")
                                            // but game crash and warning null throw 
                                            // i cant understand why and how to fix it?
        }
    }
}
```